# Обновление dpkg и строго debiana

Tags: debian

Ситуация следующая, имеется рабочая машина с ядром 2.3.
`Grub 0.9` Система `686` (что значит i386) Необходимо хотя бы обновить ядро. Через `distr update` не выходит, все репы игнорятся. Ставить пакет с ядром вручную тоже не вариант, так как `dpkg` тоже очень старый и не понимает архива `tar` внутри пакета. Я попробовал поставить мануально, распаковал архив и раскидал по папкам. Далее `update-grub` все нашлось и прописалось в `menu.list` Но при запуске появляется старая менюшка со старым ядром, без новых. В `menu.list` так же всё обнуляется.

Comment: 1. https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive 2. наиболее простой путь — пошаговое обновление. судя по версии программы linux, у вас вряд ли более старый дистрибутив, чем potato. т.е., максимум пять обновлений: potato → woody → sarge → etch → lenny → squeeze, и вот вы уже сможете обновляться дальше в «живом» репозитории.

Comment: более сложный, но короткий путь — установить новую систему рядом (если место позволяет). а «просто собрать новое ядро» с огромной вероятностью не получится (понадобится, например, новая версия gcc, которую тоже вряд ли получится собрать). но даже если получится, операционная система не сможет работать с этим новым linux-ом.